# Delete item using ANgularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a JSON file which contains data. I can print the data using ANgularJS. It will show in row with a checkbox and there is a Delete button. I want to delete the data from display and as well as from JSON file. Delete process would be like, Click on the checkbox which you want to Delete > Click on the Delete button. This is my plnkr link :-

http://plnkr.co/edit/A07XJk1RQNmhSnLFqLxH?p=preview

api.json is the JSON file.

This is the JSON file look like :-

```
{
  "1": {
    "venture": "XYZ Informatics",
    "member": [
      {
        "name": "abcd",
        "email": "abcd@gmail.com"
      }
    ],
    "message": "This is good day",
    "isclicked": false
  },
  "2": {
    "venture": "BBC Informatics",
    "member": [
      {
        "name": "xyz",
        "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
      }
    ],
    "message": "This is bad day",
    "isclicked": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ng-model` to checkbox....then iterate data and use `delete` if it is checked

```
  $scope.delete = function() {
     angular.forEach($scope.datas, function(val, key) {
       if (val.isclicked) {
         delete $scope.datas[key];
       }
     })
   }
```

View

```
<form ng-repeat="data in datas">            
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.isclicked">{{ data.venture }}          
</form>
<button ng-click="delete()">Delete</button>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/NMqHHaTDxoUjbfY0hDbk?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: It is deleting item but not updating the JSON

Comment: What do you mean not updating the json? JSON is string data you get from server. `$scope.datas` has been updated... that's why view changes

Comment: To remove from file you need to send data to server and use server code to change file

Comment: Suppose, there is a API call /api/delete:id (Where id =1, 2), to delete. Then ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your data is on the scope, you'd use the JavaScript delete function to remove an item from the array.

So...

```
delete $scope.data["1"]
```

Angular's digest should update anything watching that scope property automatically.